# How to start app on a certain time when the app is closed

Tags: android, alarm

I need to make an alarm app that opens on a custom selected time (comes forward on the screen even if the app is closed ). Using alarm manager/ broadcast receiver i managed to show notification , but not to start the app.

Comment: you need jobSchedule .

Comment: You can start an activity the same way you are showing the notification. Just start the activity intent from the broadcast onReceive method when its being triggered by the alram manager.

Comment: I'm getting this error :   Type mismatch : iferred type is Intent but Context was exepected (   val myintent = Intent(context,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(myintent) )

Answer (score 0):

You can start any activity like this from broadcast receiver:

```
public class Example extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Type mismatch : iferred type is Intent but Context was exepected

Comment: what is the problem?